# Add value to box and refresh using Javascript. Then get value in code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

I have an aspx page that has a textbox. The user opens a modal window in this page to do a search and selects an item. When selected the value is passed into a textbox in the aspx page and then refreshes.

What I then want to do is get the value in the textbox after refresh. In my code-behind it hits the page load with is fine but the value is always "" rather than the text inside it.

How can I go about getting the value after the JS has refreshed that page? Is it a matter of adding it into the right part of the page lifecyle?

Please note that the modal window does not return the value through querystring, it does it by setting the value of the box in the parent:

```
window.top.document.getElementById('txtCustomerType').value = value;
```

Then does a refresh:

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

This is the code that I use to test what the value is after refresh (page load):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string test;
     test = txtCustomerType.Text;
}
```

But the value of txtcustomertype.text comes out as "" even though it has a value.

Comment: If you refresh your page, surely the textbox value cleared

Comment: To be honest the refresh may not be the best option. I need to send the value to the textbox and then do another search and fill the only textboxes on screen. I only know how to do that in the code-behind so I am trying to hit the page load and get the value. As a matter of fact all I need to do is pass back that value then use it to get the other information.

Answer (score 1):

> If you refresh your page, surely the textbox value will be clear.

So i think you need to use hidden field or remove the `window.parent.location.reload();`

**Update**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string test;
     test = txtCustomerType.Text;
}
```

When you reload the page, The textbox value should be there at this time because it's a old textbox value, but any values not will assign in page load for new load . SO  the textbox was refresh (reload) on end of the load event.

So you should need this way

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string test;
         test = txtCustomerType.Text;
            txtCustomerType.Text=txtCustomerType.Text
    }
```

In above code will assign the old textbox value to second time.

> If you use runat server in your textbox, then you need to clientId for read a textbox in javascript

Comment: But then how do I get that value in the code-behind? It will never do a postback like this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the .text comes back as "" so when I assign it back to the txtcustomertype, it is still ""

Comment: did you put break point in page load event? for which time the textbox will clear.

Comment: I think your javascript code is shown error. please run ie browser

Comment: I have tested in IE and Chrome and the JS works fine, I do get to the breakpoint but as I said the value is ""